# Difference between radiant power and radiant flux

Tags: electromagnetism, terminology, spectroscopy, radiometry

In [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiant_flux) the definition of radiant flux is: radiant energy per unit of time.

(deriving w.r.t area you get the  radiant exitance or radiant emittance).

So this means that the radiant flux is the energy radiated from the total surface of a body that is radiating this energy per unit of time.

Then for the [Stefan-Boltzmann in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan%E2%80%93Boltzmann_law) it says:

> To find the total power radiated from an object, multiply by its surface area A: $P = A j^{\star}$ where $j^{\star}$ is the radiant emittance for electromagnetic waves.

So why are Power and radiant flux called different names, when they represent the same thing, energy per unit of time, with unit W ?